# What is the chain rule when you want to change different variables with respect to different derivatives?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Assuming I have $u=z*h$ and $z^2=k*x$

How can I convert

$\frac{\mathrm{d} h}{\mathrm{d} x}->\frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} z}$

I am convinced it involves using the chain rule. But I am unsure how I plug these in?

Am I supposed to do it like this?

$\frac{\mathrm{d} D}{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{\mathrm{d} D}{\mathrm{d} z}*\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x} = \frac{k}{2\sqrt{kx}}$

$\frac{\mathrm{d} h}{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{\mathrm{d} h}{\mathrm{d} u}*\frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{d} z}*\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{kuh}{2z\sqrt{kx}}$

$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 h}{\mathrm{d} x^2}=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x}*\frac{\mathrm{d} h}{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{k}{2\sqrt{kx}}$

$\frac{\mathrm{d} b}{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{\mathrm{d} b}{\mathrm{d} z}*\frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x}=\frac{3k^2uh}{4z(kx)^{3/2}}$

Also once I have a solution in terms of x and h, and I don't know how to plug it back into my general equation to get $du/dz$

Comment: What are $D$ and $b$? They are not mentioned in the question's preamble.

Comment: $D=\frac{Do}{Xo}X$ and $B=\frac{Bo}{Xo}X$

Comment: Your working doesn't seem to match the question you have asked. Are you asking the following question : "express $\frac{du}{dz}$ in terms of $\frac{dh}{dx}$"? The subsequent working doesn't seem cohesive, that's why I'm  asking.  I can see four new quantities that  are not in the question, for example.  But the aforementioned question can be done via the chain rule.